# Оптимизировать MySQL запрос фреймворк Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

Доброго времени суток, друзья. Помогите оптимизировать запрос для фильтрации данных. 
Есть такой запрос, сейчас он отрабатывает 1,5 секунды. Возможно ли как то ускорить его работу?

```
EXPLAIN SELECT r.id, o.name AS objectName,
                            (SELECT MAX(d2.`valuePercent`) FROM discounts AS d2
                                                           JOIN `rooms` AS r2 ON d2.`roomId` = r2.id
                                                           WHERE r2.objectId = r.objectId) AS `valuePercent`,
                            d.type, o.stars, o.`infoAboutObject`, o.id AS objectId, o.url,
                            r.`price`, o.`address`, o.`image`, c.`name` AS cityName, o.longitudeGps, o.latitudeGps,

                            (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT otp1.`class` SEPARATOR ',') FROM objects_types_pluses AS otp1
                            JOIN objects_objects_types_pluses AS ot1 ON ot1.`objectTypePlusesId` = otp1.id WHERE ot1.`objectId` = o.id)
                            AS className,

                            (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT otp1.`name` SEPARATOR ',') FROM objects_types_pluses AS otp1
                            JOIN objects_objects_types_pluses AS ot1 ON ot1.`objectTypePlusesId` = otp1.id WHERE ot1.`objectId` = o.id)
                            AS pluseName,

                            (SELECT COUNT(rev.id) FROM reviews AS rev WHERE rev.objectId = o.`id`) AS reviewCount,
                            (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT os1.`name` SEPARATOR ',') FROM objects_servises AS os1
                            JOIN objects_relation_objects_servises AS oros ON oros.`objectServiceId` = os1.id WHERE oros.`objectId` = o.id)
                            AS objectsServisesName,
                            GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT os.`name` SEPARATOR ',') AS objectsServisesName,
                            o.raitingValue
                            FROM objects AS o
                            JOIN cities AS c ON o.`cityId` = c.`id`
                            LEFT JOIN objects_objects_types_pluses AS op ON op.`objectId` = o.id
                            LEFT JOIN `objects_types_pluses` AS otp ON op.`objectTypePlusesId` = otp.`id`
                            JOIN rooms AS r ON o.`id` = r.`objectId`
                            LEFT JOIN discounts AS d ON r.`id` = d.`roomId`
                            LEFT JOIN objects_relation_objects_servises AS oros ON o.`id` = oros.`objectId`
                            LEFT JOIN objects_servises AS os ON oros.objectServiceId = os.`id`
                            WHERE (
                                    d.`valuePercent` =
                                    (
                                        SELECT MAX(d1.`valuePercent`)
                                            FROM discounts AS d1
                                            JOIN `rooms` AS r1 ON d1.`roomId` = r1.id
                                            WHERE r1.objectId = r.objectId


                                    ) OR d.`valuePercent` IS NULL
                                  )  AND c.countryId = 1
                            GROUP BY o.id
                             LIMIT 7 OFFSET 0
```

[image: Результат с explain]

Comment: Чтобы понять как работает запрос внутри MySQL можно использовать EXPLAIN. Приложите, пожалуйста, к вопросу результат работы запроса EXPLAIN <тело-оптимизируемого-запроса>. Подробнее про EXPLAIN можно прочитать здесь https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html

Comment: Спасибо, добавил скрин.

Comment: В строке про таблицу `rooms` в колонке `type` стоит `ALL`, а в `extra` - `Using temporary; Using filesort`. А в самом запросе `GROUP BY` происходит по колонке из таблицы `objects`. Таблицы `rooms` и `objects` связаны через `JOIN rooms AS r ON o.`id` = r.`objectId`. Т.е. может быть что-то не так с индексами таблицы `rooms` или `objects`. Приложите к вопросу результаты запросов `SHOW INDEX FROM rooms` и `SHOW INDEX FROM objects`, пожалуйста

Comment: Но, а вообще, так можно ещё долго удалённо оптимизировать. В любом случае, нужно смотреть в результат запроса EXPLAIN. Например, посмотреть в строки, где в `type` есть значение `ALL` и как-то модифицировать запрос. Например, `discounts` присоединяется через LEFT JOIN, а в WHERE есть условие с колонкой этой таблицы.